# Pandas plot bar graph with datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, bar-chart, datetime-format

I have the following dataframe:

```
gr_data = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SUN')])['name'].count()


print(gr_data)

    date
    2018-08-19     582
    2018-09-02    1997
    2018-09-16    3224
    2018-10-07    4282
    2018-10-28    5618
    2018-11-04    5870
    Freq: W-SUN, Name: name, dtype: int64
```

I am plotting this data using [plot.bar()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar)

`'date'` is a `datetime64[ns]` type.

When I plot the data hours/minutes/seconds are visible. How do drop the hours/minutes/seconds?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert them with `strfttime`. You might want to ensure the `dates` are sorted before plotting so it always plots in time order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gr_data.sort_index(inplace=True) #Ensure plotting in time order

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gr_data.assign(dates = gr_data.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).plot(kind='bar', x='dates', ax=ax)

fig.autofmt_xdate()  #Rotate the dates so they aren't squished
plt.show()
```

[image]